# Why is onPrepareDialog being called when I press the back button?

Tags: android-dialog

I have three android phones for development. A Galaxy S, a Galaxy S3, and an HTC one X. On the S and the HTC, my app works fine. However, on the S3, there is a strange bug.

I open a `Dialog` in the main activity, and then `dismiss()` it. Then I go forward to another activity. Then I press the back button, and, for some reason, the `onPrepareDialog()` method of the main activity runs, with the closed `Dialog` as it's argument. This will either do nothing (from the point of view of the user), or it might crash, because `onPrepareDialog()` expects the app to be in a certain state that it isn't in such a circumstance.

Now, obviously, I shouldn't be letting it lose a good state like that, or I should be handling when it does.  I will fix the issues regardless of the answer to this question. But **Why is the `onPrepareDialog()` method being called in the first place, and why is it only causing problems on the S3?**

(I have just realised it's possible that the S3 is not the only one running the method, and instead is the only one that's losing state, but I don't actually have any real idea.)